# Can two devices with different static IP addresses find eachother?

Tags: networking

The setup I currently have is two computers connected through a crossover cable. I am trying to use the command line or Python to find the ip address of the other computer. Is there any way I could get one of the computers to find the ip address of the other computer if they are on a different network number?

Comment: You need to have different numbers, but they have to be in the same subnet, which can be of different size, depending on the number. For example, in the reserved area of 192.168.x.y, the subnets are 256 IPs big, afaik, while in 10.0.x.y it is (afaik) 256*256 IPs big. Since I know nothing of python, this is just a comment. I only know how to search with `nmap` or `ping`.

Comment: Could you comment on the IPs currently assigned ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on the network mask. Depending on the network mask used, the same IP address can end up in different networks. To communicate directly (without routers involved), two devices need to be on the same network.

Have a look at this post: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/164015

Comment: Thanks. This is what I suspected but I was hoping to avoid having to bring a router/switch.

Comment: @Adam: I don't mean that it will work with just a switch. Someone should still assign the IPs (a switch doesn't assign ip's, and if the computers have a static address, they won't listen to DHCP assignments). Since you have direct access to both computers, the simplest is to set their IPs, or have one act as a DHCP server, or just take the other computer's IP +1, so it's on the same network with whichever reasonable mask you're using. So you can avoid the need for a router. Give more details and we might help you more.